# Alternative to scalerel? Issues in combination with table of contents

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, fontsize, subscripts, scalerel

**Issue:** My Latex files are pretty big already, but lately I added the `scalerel` package and since then get the error message

**! Undefined control sequence.\calc@initB ->\calc@B\calc@A \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}**

However the interesting thing is, once I remove the package I still run into errors, I need to reload my .tex file to make it work again.

I finally figured out that the package in combination with `\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}` causes the error.

**Question:** Is there any incompatibility of the package scalerel with certain settings or other packages known? Or is there any altnerative to get my subspricts that small?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,         
        12pt,                   
        bibliography=totoc,     
        index=totoc,            
        parskip=false
        ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literatur_Citavi.bib} 

\usepackage{scalerel}           % scale math even smaller

\begin{document}                
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}} % here comes the trouble

$\varphi_{\scaleto{sig}{3pt}}$

\nocite{Kister.2019, Blankertz.2019}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you want to set the tocdepth _in_ the toc??? (`\protect\setcounter` probably works, but it seems a very strange construct)

Comment: there is no need to use scaling to get small subscripts you can use  `\DeclareMathSizes` to declare the font sizes to use for subscripts at each main font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "fragile command in a moving argument" error, so the standard `\protect` command avoids the error

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}} % here comes the trouble
```

But changing the tocdepth within the table of contents seems a rather odd thing to do?

Comment: thanks for your answer that actually solved the issue. 

I did this because I wanted to have my Appendix sections numbered as A.1, A.2,.. and so on, but not listed in the table of contents, so it would only appear as A Appendix